# Is there any notification which can capture Reachability event on iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, reachability, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

iPhone 6/6 Plus have new feature named "Reachability" (Touch twice on TouchID to interact on the larger screen). But I don't find any API in iOS8 SDK documentation.Perhaps I have to wait for the next version of iOS SDK.

I think my App can do something interesting or make some surprise when Reachability active. So anyone has idea for it?

Comment: I tried to check if there's any difference in UIWindow frame size, but with no luck. Looks like it's more a low-level operation.

Comment: I think this is just not supposed to do anything surprising. The Reachability event should just bring the screen closer down for the user to be able to reach it with their thumbs. Modifying the appearance of the app at that point is, in my opinion, counter-intuitive. Imagine that I cannot reach a button that is at the top of the view, then I double tap the TouchID and expect the button to be roughly at the middle of the screen height but hey, you just placed it somewhere else and now I am confused..:)

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the iOS 8.x SDK changes, it's not possible for an app to detect that the user has activated Reachability. I think that Apple want (and expect) that this feature will simply allow access to the top half of the screen, and handles the relocate of the base view completely transparently to the app. I can't point you to any specific documentation on this, as it's a case of the absence of proof being itself proof.

Oh, and I don't think Apple wants any apps doing anything "surprising" when Reachability is activated! ;-)